# Proper way to document that a class implements a collections interface?

Tags: python, python-collections

Assuming I have a class that implements the Sequence interface, i.e. has `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods, what is the recommended way to document this? Is an informal description in the classes docstring enough, should I subclass `collections.abc.Sequence` or do something else entirely?

Comment: If you subclass `Sequence`, you automatically get implementations of `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__reversed__`, `index`, and `count`. Do you want that?

Comment: Originally I didn't because the sequence is just one attribute of the class that I wanted to forward the sequence access methods to. But I forgot that subclassing would give me Reversible and Collection as well, in that case it makes probably more sense to just subclass rather than implementing all of their methods manually. That still leaves the question how to document interface implementation though.